# Make a directory and copy a file

Tags: vbscript

In VBS how do you make a directory and then copy a file into it?

Id like to make a folder in the root of C  e.g. C:\folder and then copy a file from \server\folder\file.ext into that new folder

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use the [`FileSystemObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kxy1a51.aspx) object, namely, its [`CreateFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kby5ae3.aspx) and [`CopyFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1wf9e7w.aspx) methods. Basically, this is what your script will look like:

```
Dim oFSO
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Create a new folder
oFSO.CreateFolder "C:\MyFolder"

' Copy a file into the new folder
' Note that the destination folder path must end with a path separator (\)
oFSO.CopyFile "\\server\folder\file.ext", "C:\MyFolder\"
```

You may also want to add additional logic, like checking whether the folder you want to create already exists (because `CreateFolder` raises an error in this case) or specifying whether or not to overwrite the file being copied. So, you can end up with this:

```
Const strFolder = "C:\MyFolder\", strFile = "\\server\folder\file.ext"
Const Overwrite = True
Dim oFSO

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If Not oFSO.FolderExists(strFolder) Then
  oFSO.CreateFolder strFolder
End If

oFSO.CopyFile strFile, strFolder, Overwrite
```

Comment: Note that the destination `strFolder` must end with a \.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the shell for this purpose.

```
Set shl = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
shl.Run "cmd mkdir YourDir" & copy "
```